# How to layout contents from an array in table format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

At the moment I have a function in my web app which allows an employer to view all the people who have applied for their jobs.

For each applicant it should show their skills within one column, their qualifications in another, work history in another and it should do this for each applicant.

e.g

The applications database table has a column `'jobseeker_profile_id'` which maps to the jobseeker_profiles table `'id'` column. Using the `'jobseeker_profile_id'` from the applications table I should be able to then go through the skills, qualifications and work_history database tables and get where the `'jobseeker_profile_id'` within each of those tables matches the one in the applications table.

What I am asking is how to lay this out so that all the skills, qualifications and work history for each applicant is on the correct row?

As you will see below I have done `print_r()` for each array and they contain the correct data in the correct order but unsure how to get that data and display it within a table.

```
print_r($skills):
Array([0] = > Array([0] = > Array([id] = > 42[name] = > HTML[level] = > 4[jobseeker_profile_id] = > 4[points_value] = > 4))[1] = > Array([0] = > Array([id] = > 41[name] = > CSS[level] = > 2[jobseeker_profile_id] = > 2[points_value] = > 2)[1] = > Array([id] = > 39[name] = > PHP[level] = > 3[jobseeker_profile_id] = > 2[points_value] = > 3)))
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    $data = array();

    $data['applications'] = $this->db->get_where('applications', array('employer_profile_id' => $employer_id, 'job_id' => $job_id ))->result_array();

    foreach($data['applications'] as $jobseeker){
        $data['skill'] = $this->db->get_where('skills', array('jobseeker_profile_id' => $jobseeker['jobseeker_profile_id']))->result_array();
        $data['qualification'] = $this->db->get_where('qualifications', array('jobseeker_profile_id' => $jobseeker['jobseeker_profile_id']))->result_array();       
        $data['history'] = $this->db->get_where('work_history', array('jobseeker_profile_id' => $jobseeker['jobseeker_profile_id']))->result_array();
        $data['skills'][] = $data['skill'];
        $data['qualifications'][] = $data['qualification'];
        $data['workhistory'][] = $data['history'];
    }   

    $this->load->view('applications', $data);
```

**VIEW**

```
foreach($applications as $application){

echo "<tbody style=\"background:green;\">";

$value = $application['points_value'] * $this->session->userdata('price');

echo "<tr class=\"row\">";  
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo $application['name'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
print_r($skills);
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
print_r($qualifications);
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
print_r($workhistory);
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo $value;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo form_checkbox('jobseeker[]', $application['jobseeker_profile_id']);
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
}
```

If anyone can help then that would be great :)

Comment: Just a comment, I think the tbody opening and closing tags should go outside of the loop

Comment: Just a nifty tip. If you use echo '<pre>'; print_r($skills); echo '</pre>'; You will get a much more readable array printed to the screen!

Comment: @davidaam Yip that's correct, thanks.

Comment: @Austin I see, would you be able to help me with the problem, any solutions?

Comment: @learn So far after looking this over for a little bit, what you are asking is for someone to code this for you. Basically what you are going to need to do, is take a break for a bit, play some Portal 2 or whatever you like, and then after your brain has had some time to cool off, jump in and start programming. Here is an article that I think will really help make it easier to read and code this for your self. http://www.askaboutphp.com/59/phps-alternative-syntax-and-why-its-useful.html

Comment: @Austin no I'm not looking for someone to code it I'm looking for help and suggestions about how I would go about it.

Comment: I would recommend designing a table to help you conceptualize the data that needs to be displayed. You can try a table generator to help with that: http://askthecssguy.com/kotatsu/  Once you get the table designed and you know what data is going to be displayed and where exactly in the table each piece of data will be, its just a matter of thinking about how to integrate the foreach loop(s) within the table HTML to output the data in each cell. That is where my earlier link will come in handy. Also regularly print out your data arrays to help you locate the data you need to output!

Comment: I'm rather unsure of the syntax for getting the array results to display because it is showing errors when i try and do a foreach